# imported config products are not getting associated

Tags: php, magento, config, magento-1.7, associated-types

I am using Magento 1.7.  I am able to successfully import configurable products, but  associated products are not getting linked to it. I have to manually link them through my admin. How can I link them through csv file?

Comment: how does your import file look like?

Comment: store,websites,attribute_set,type,sku,sheet_color,fittedsheet_size,sheet_pattern,price,weight,name,short_description,description,status,visibility,tax_class_id,qty,is_in_stock,options_container,associated,config_attributes,tier_prices,super_attribute_pricing,has_option,required_options,handling_time,category_ids,country_of_manufacture,care_instructions,,wd_shippingcost1,wd_shippingcost2,meta_title,meta_keyword,meta_description,search_words

Comment: where sheet_color, fittedsheet_size, sheets_pattern are config attributes

Comment: I Don't think you can with magento's standard import stuff

Answer (score 1):

Magento import profile does not support this. you may to import your products first then What you may have to do is to write a custom module to override the import functinality, where a another csv containing the association between you configurable products and simple products.

makign this association would be relatively simple, 
[how to add configurable products programmatically](http://learntipsandtricks.com/blog/magento/184/Magento-How-to-assign-simple-products-to-configurable-programmatically)